# Low quality question solved in the comments, what to do?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23345238/python-sqlalchemy-import-not-working) about installing a Python library has actually nothing to do with that library, it's only caused by a unexperienced user who types Python code directly in his terminal without running the interpreter.

After a few comments he [realizes his mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23345238/python-sqlalchemy-import-not-working#comment35751338_23345238) and that's it - and the question remains unanswered but no good answer is possible since there's no real problem related to Python or that library, just a beginner's mistake.

In my opinion, this question has no value since it isn't about a real problem with the Python library and is misleading (someone having a **real** problem with that library will stumble upon this question and waste his time reading it).

I downvoted it but I feel like there's something else to do, I don't yet have access to close votes but I'm tempted to flag it as low quality.

Is this the right thing to do or is that question good enough to stay open ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The question should end up closed. In the meantime, though, posting an "acceptable" answer seems like a good way to indicate that the problem is no longer unanswered or unsolved, until the question amasses enough close votes (or in case it never does).

If the asker doesn't self-answer based on their error, and the commenter who found the real root cause doesn't promote their comment to an answer, it may make sense to post a Community Wiki answer that says "Resolved in comments: the OP wasn't aware they needed to run in a terminal" or equivalent. I like to put a credited quote of the answering comment into the CW answer itself, for posterity, and because it more-directly fits the Q&A format.

([Here's an example of this technique in action.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23175564/1426891) It seems to me like the best move in a less-than-ideal situation, but I'll gladly take feedback if the consensus is against it.)

Comment: +1. I would take a harder line and suggest such questions be deleted, but I like this as the alternative.

Comment: @chepner I've come across questions like these when starting out with a new language/framework while making the *same* beginner mistake. Oftentimes simple errors result in the same error messages or outcome, and even if they don't *exactly* fit someone else's problem, the issue can often be fixed by the solution in the original question. Having these questions around, even when they're closed, help prevent more like them from being created.

Answer (score 26):

There is a close sub-reason for "offtopic" just for these types of cases:

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: Yes but as I said before I don't yet have access to close votes, so should I flag bad questions like that one as low quality ?

Comment: @André You should flag the question for closure, using that specific reason.  Do not flag a question as low quality if it should be closed; flag it for closure.