# Filter questions by number of comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, search

I would like a [search filter](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) similar to `answers:<number>`, but for the number of comments on the original question (`comments:<number>`).

Specifically, I would like to use this in order to find questions that have absolutely no replies whatsoever, not even comments, and try to help those people out.

I'm aware that, in theory, questions that are answered in the comments should either end up closed or get a proper answer, but the reality is that there are still countless such questions which completely overshadow those that *actually* need help when you search for [unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered). Wanting all those to be answered properly or closed before questions with zero answers and comments show up means prioritising formality over actually helping people.

This is related to, for instance, [How to skip unanswered questions but with comments that solved the problem?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262860), except I'm asking for this feature to be implemented because I don't find the answer given there satisfactory.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I put together a quick and dirty query that may get you what you're after for the time being:

[Questions with no answers and no comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/363121/questions-with-no-answers-and-no-comments)

```
select TOP 30
  p.Id as [Post Link]
  FROM Posts p
  WHERE 
  p.PostTypeId = 1 AND 
  p.score >= 0 AND
  p.closeddate is null AND
  ISNULL(p.AnswerCount,0) = 0 AND
  ISNULL(p.CommentCount,0) = 0 
  order by p.score desc
```

You may get a few false positives, comments posted after the last dump aren't detected...

Feel free to edit as needed, I don't have much experience with these so I'm sure it could use some tweaking.

Answer (score 10):

A close enough alternative *was* to look at questions with the [Tumbleweed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed) badge: if a post receives no comments or answers for a week, it's likely to stay that way for some time.

However, this badge was [retired in June 2019](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/).

Comment: Excellent idea, thank you! But this badge is only awarded once for each user, isn't it? So if someone asks two questions that get nothing, won't only the first show up?

Comment: @pmos Yeah, it's awarded [only once](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21296/why-cant-the-tumbleweed-badge-be-awarded-multiple-times) per user. That's still ~600k questions to look at, you won't run out any time soon.