# Searching for not only non commented and non answered as well as specific phrases

Tags: support, answers, comments, search, data-explorer

Following the question posted on linked page:

[Filter questions by number of comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305917/filter-questions-by-number-of-comments)

I would like to search for those questions that have 0 answers, 0 comments, but also specific phrases - such as "Excel" and "VBA".

What would I need to add / change in that query in dataexplorer to do this?

Comment: Probably something as simple as adding a `WHERE p.body like '%Excel%' OR p.title like '%Excel%'`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

As indicated by [Rob](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/563532/rob) I forked the [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/445776/questions-with-no-answers-and-no-comments?phrase=excel) to implement his suggestion:

```sql
-- Questions with no answers and no comments

declare @phrase nvarchar(200) = ##phrase:string##

select TOP 30
  p.Id as [Post Link]
  FROM Posts p
  WHERE 
  p.PostTypeId = 1 AND 
  p.score >= 0 AND
  p.closeddate is null AND
  ISNULL(p.AnswerCount,0) = 0 AND
  ISNULL(p.CommentCount,0) = 0 AND
  (p.body like '%' + @phrase +'%' 
  or p.title like '%' + @phrase + '%') 
  order by p.score desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks, my query is on page linked below:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/446466/no-comments-no-answers-and-title-or-body-contains-excel