# How to find "lonely" questions?

Tags: support, search

One of my favourite ways to find unanswered but well asked questions is by using the query:

> [tag] answers:0 score:n

Where `n` is some positive integer. I then sort by newest and look for questions I can help with.

The problem with this query is that I find **a lot** of questions that have been answered via a back and forth discussion in the comments

Putting aside the fact that these questions should have a real answer, what I would really like in search is a way to get rid of this noise and find those that have been completely ignored: No Answers, No Comments, and a positive score. Is this doable?

It seems like the query is available through this API: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search, but putting variations on `comment_count:0` in the url for the site proper does not seem to work.

Comment: You can use Data Explorer [like so](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/363128/questions-with-no-answers-and-no-comments-older-than-2-days-tagged-python-sor), but the data may be up to a week old. Otherwise, write a script that retrieves questions using the API search capability, and then drops those with comments_count>0.

Comment: @404 Can u give the option to edit tag also in that query.

Comment: If a comment gives the answer, ideally, someone should repost it as an actual answer. Note that just because there are comments, does not mean that one of them is an answer.

Comment: This seems meta^2- is one of the earlier comments here the answer?

Comment: @404 unfortunately the "week old" issue makes the first solution tricky. Most of the ones I checked have an answer by the time the query runs (it is still useful if I exclude more recent results, so kudos). As for the second,  I would prefer an in-browser solution if one is available

Comment: Maybe you can do something with the [tumbleweed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed) badge.

Comment: @nwp Clever - the question that the badge was awarded for doesn't seem to be a part of the query schema though, which is strange since your link clearly associates the two

Comment: @nwp Not for positively scored posts, which is what OP is looking for.

Comment: @Chris Not really strange: criteria for badges are implemented in server side code that is entirely different from the search engine.

Comment: Related: [Filter questions by number of comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305917)

Comment: `Find hot unanswered questions in your area`

Answer (score 8):

The following userscript leverages the [Advanced/search](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=activity&answers=0&tagged=haskell&filter=!9YdnSHlY(&site=stackoverflow&run=true) API of the StackAPI to get an in initial result. It then uses JavaScript to filter out the unwanted rows. The qualifying rows are presented as a link.

The script does paging but the filtering doesn't allow to limit the results very much so on large tags it might take a while before all result are in.

```js
var rows = document.getElementById('rows'),
    search = document.getElementById('search'),
    feedback = document.getElementById('feedback'),
    tag = document.getElementById('tag'),
    score = document.getElementById('score'),
    comments = document.getElementById('comments'),
    answers = document.getElementById('answers'),
    tot,
    processed;

function buildRow(item) {
  var row = document.createElement('div'),
      a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = item.link;
  a.textContent = item.title;
  row.appendChild(a);
  rows.appendChild(row);
  }

function buildApiUrl(urlParts, queryString) {
  var url = '',
      qp,
      queryArr = [];
  
  url = urlParts.join('/');
  if (queryString !== undefined) { 
    for(qp in queryString) {
      queryArr.push(qp + '=' + queryString[qp]); 
    }
    url = url + '?' + queryArr.join('&');
  }
  return url;
}

function handleApiResponse(response, page) {
  var i, 
      resp = JSON.parse(response),
      items = resp.items;
  if (page === undefined) {
    while (rows.firstChild) {
      rows.removeChild(rows.firstChild);
    }
    page = 1;
    tot = 0;
    processed = 0;
    search.disabled = true;
  }
 
  if (items.length > 0) {
    for(i = 0; i < items.length; i = i + 1) {
      if (items[i].comment_count === parseInt(comments.value, 10) &&
          items[i].answer_count === parseInt(answers.value, 10) &&
          items[i].score === parseInt(score.value, 10) 
         ) {
        tot = tot + 1;
        buildRow(items[i]);
      }
    }
    processed = processed + items.length;
    feedback.textContent = '# results: ' + processed + ' # filtered: ' + tot;
  } else {
    if (page === 1) {
      feedback.textContent = 'no questions found';
    }
  }
  if (resp.has_more) {
    if (resp.backoff) {
      setTimeout(function() { sendRequest(page + 1); }, resp.backoff * 1000);
    } else {
      sendRequest(page + 1);
    }
  } else {
    search.disabled = false;
  }
}

function sendRequest(page) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
      api = [ 'https://api.stackexchange.com',
             '2.2',
             'search',
             'advanced'], 
      qs = {
        'order':'desc',
        'sort':'activity',
        'pagesize': 100,
        'answers': parseInt(answers.value, 10),
        'tagged': tag.value,
        'site': 'stackoverflow',
        'filter': '!9YdnSHlY(',
        'key': 'I4Ll0m749uHMyBd9S74DkA(('
        };
   
  if (page !== undefined) {
    qs.page = page;
  }   
  xhr.addEventListener('load', function () {
      handleApiResponse(xhr.responseText, page);
  });

  xhr.open('GET', buildApiUrl(api, qs));
  xhr.send();
}

search.addEventListener('click', function() { sendRequest(); });
```

```css
label {
  width: 100px;
  display:inline-block;
  }

div {
  margin: 10px;
  }

div.results 
{
  margin: 5px;
}

div.results div
{
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
  <label for="tag">Tag</label><input id="tag" type="text" value="haskell" />
  </div>
  <div>
  <label for="score">Score</label><input id="score" type="text" value="0"/>
  </div>
  <div>
  <label for="answers">Answers</label><input id="answers" type="text" value="0"/>
  </div>
  <div>
  <label for="comments">Comments</label><input id="comments" type="text" value="0"/>
  </div>
  <div>
  <button id="search">Search</button>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="result" class="results">
  <div id="feedback">No results</div>
  <div id="rows">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Chris sure [here you go](https://gist.github.com/rschrieken/6b3f7cc83e4997c7cef9b8d91d5bd957). Html file that you can store locally and then open in your browser.